# Better way to make arrays from arraylists?

Tags: java, regex, arrays, string, arraylist

The problem here is that I've been trying (and not succeeding) to grab the source code of a website and find some text, then put that on a jLabel.

The part of getting the code is done and works just fine, I am really having a big issue when I try to get the results of the code (using regular expressions) and put each result into a different String (and then, using setText() method, put them on a different jLabel).

I've asked in many forums and they told me to use ArrayLists:

```
Matcher m = p.matcher(code); 

while (m.find()) {
    String grupo = m.group(1);
    ArrayList lista = new ArrayList();
    lista.add(0,grupo);
    for(int i = 0;i<lista.size();i++){
        System.out.println(lista.get(i));
```

In this code, theorically, the program finds the code according to some patterns that I set before and "saves" the results into an ArrayList.

The big deal is that I'm not being able to put each result into a different string, and the program keeps telling me on the console that the arraylist has size 1, and the saved results has like, 10 or 12 elements.
However,  when I run the program with that code, it shows me all the elements.

Comment: The issue is you are re-creating the list inside the loop. Declare the list outside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use generics and structure your code as follows:

```
ArrayList<String> lista = new ArrayList<>();
while (m.find()) {
    String grupo = m.group(1);
    lista.add(0, grupo);
}
```

You can then print the list elements:

```
for (String str : lista) {
    System.out.println(str);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Now, i need a way to print one of those elements into a string, for example, a string which contains the element 3 of that list.

Comment: @SebastiánPazPereira: `lista.get(2);` returns the third element of the list.

Comment: That helped me a lot. But do you know why does that list now it appears to show upside down? I need a way to turn it around

Comment: @SebastiánPazPereira: use `lista.add(grupo);` instead of `lista.add(0, grupo);`

Comment: @SebaPaz: If this solves your problem, please accept the answer (green checkmark) to let the community know the question is solved.

Comment: Yes, I'm doing that because the whole problem is now solved. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

import java.util.Collections;

List myList = new ArrayList();
String[] myArray = new String[] {"Java", "Util", "List"};

Collections.addAll(myList, myArray);